# How to limit bandwidth to a set of hosts

Tags: openwrt, trafficshaping

I'd like to limit bandwidth to a set of local hosts by adding an appropriate config to my router.

IIUC I can limit the bandwidth like I want with:

```
tc qdisc add dev $IF root tbf burst 1mb rate 100kbps
```

Except that this affects all machines connected to `$IF`, whereas I only want some of them to be affected. I figured that I can tag the relevant packets with something like:

```
iptables -t mangle -A POSTROUTING -j CLASSIFY \
         --dst 192.168.1.128/25 --set-class 1:10
```

However, the missing part I can't figure out is which classful scheduler to use on `$IF`, and how to add a `tbf` queue for those packets of the `1:10` class.

[ BTW, I see someone voted to close this question.  Any idea why?  Would there be a better place to ask such questions?  ]